# Metadata in wmf file?

Tags: c#, .net, wmf

Is there a way to store and retrieve custom metadata in a [wmf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) file, please notice that i don't mean [Windows Media Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Format#Formats)?

Optional using .net and C# ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no", as WMF doesn't support meta data other than basic things like type, version, size and number of items.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving the info you can refer the following path.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MetaDataReader.aspx
```

Moreover you need to download the WMF SDK. Using following link.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=d9c6f6e0-dd2b-427e-9787-73312bb62532
```

It supports following attributes.

```
Index    Name                   Stream Language Type  
 -----    ------                 ------ -------- ----  
   0      Duration                    0    0    QWORD  
   1      Bitrate                     0    0    DWORD  
   2      Seekable                    0    0     BOOL  
   3      Stridable                   0    0     BOOL  
   4      Broadcast                   0    0     BOOL  
   5      Is_Protected                0    0     BOOL  
   6      Is_Trusted                  0    0     BOOL  
   7      Signature_Name              0    0   STRING  
   8      HasAudio                    0    0     BOOL  
   9      HasImage                    0    0     BOOL  
  10      HasScript                   0    0     BOOL  
  11      HasVideo                    0    0     BOOL  
  12      CurrentBitrate              0    0    DWORD  
  13      OptimalBitrate              0    0    DWORD  
  14      HasAttachedImages           0    0     BOOL  
  15      Can_Skip_Backward           0    0     BOOL  
  16      Can_Skip_Forward            0    0     BOOL  
  17      FileSize                    0    0    QWORD  
  18      HasArbitraryDataStream      0    0     BOOL  
  19      HasFileTransferStream       0    0     BOOL  
  20      WM/ContainerFormat          0    0    DWORD  
  21      Title                       0    0   STRING  
  22      Author                      0    0   STRING  
  23      Copyright                   0    0   STRING  
  24      Description                 0    0   STRING  
  25      Rating                      0    0   STRING  
  26      BannerImageURL              0    0   STRING  
  27      CopyrightURL                0    0   STRING  
  28      WMFSDKVersion               0    0   STRING  
  29      WMFSDKNeeded                0    0   STRING  
  30      IsVBR                       0    0     BOOL  
  31      WM/AlbumTitle               0    0   STRING  
  32      WM/Track                    0    0   STRING  
  33      WM/PromotionURL             0    0   STRING  
  34      WM/AlbumCoverURL            0    0   STRING  
  35      WM/Genre                    0    0   STRING  
  36      WM/Year                     0    0   STRING  
  37      WM/GenreID                  0    0   STRING  
  38      WM/Composer                 0    0   STRING  
  39      WM/Lyrics                   0    0   STRING  
  40      WM/ToolName                 0    0   STRING  
  41      WM/ToolVersion              0    0   STRING  
  42      WM/AlbumArtist              0    0   STRING  
  43      WM/AuthorURL                0    0   STRING  
  44      WM/AudioFileURL             0    0   STRING  
  45      WM/Language                 0    0   STRING  
  46      WM/ParentalRating           0    0   STRING  
  47      WM/BeatsPerMinute           0    0   STRING  
  48      WM/InitialKey               0    0   STRING  
  49      WM/Mood                     0    0   STRING  
  50      WM/DVDID                    0    0   STRING  
  51      WM/UniqueFileIdentifier     0    0   STRING  
  52      WM/ModifiedBy               0    0   STRING  
  53      WM/RadioStationName         0    0   STRING  
  54      WM/RadioStationOwner        0    0   STRING  
  55      WM/PlaylistDelay            0    0   STRING  
  56      WM/Codec                    0    0   STRING  
  57      WM/DRM                      0    0   STRING  
  58      WM/ISRC                     0    0   STRING  
  59      WM/Provider                 0    0   STRING  
  60      WM/ProviderRating           0    0   STRING  
  61      WM/ProviderStyle            0    0   STRING  
  62      WM/ContentDistributor       0    0   STRING  
  63      WM/SubscriptionContentID    0    0   STRING  
  64      WM/ASFPacketCount           0    0    QWORD  
  65      WM/ASFSecurityObjectsSize   0    0    QWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

WMF does not support metadata like author, title, description, etc. However, according to the [Windows Metafile Format Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/501ED102-E53F-4CE0-AA6B-B0F93629DDC6/WindowsMetafileFormat%28wmf%29Specification.pdf), page 192, comments (in your case custom metadata) can be written to MFCOMMENT printer escape.